# C# Why can't you change the variable value in the class scope?

Tags: c#

I'm confused as to why C# doesn't let you change the variable value in the class scope after defining it.

Consider the code(This will not work):

```
class Foo
{
   private int x;
   x = 0;
}
```

Obviously you can do something like

```
class Foo
{
   private int x = 0;
}
```

or this

```
class Foo
{
    private int x;
    public void Bar()
    {
        x = 5;
    }
}
```

But I don't understand why the first way doesn't work as I thought as long as the variable is within the same scope you can modify it?

Comment: that oop architecture in most languages if not all

Comment: An assigment statement like `x = 0;` can only be within a method.

Comment: Ask yourself this: If you write code directly within the class (rather than a constructor/method/property/etc), at what point would you expect that code to be executed? The answer to that question should tell you where you **should** put that code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Because this area

class Foo{ ... here ... }

designed for declaration of class. So it contais members with its default initialization and functions. You want to put functional code this is not allowed.

If you need to put construction code use constructors.

Answer (score 0):

`x=0;` can only be part of a method. In case of `private int x = 0;` compiler will actually split that and put assignment into a constructor so you would have compiled version of

```
class Foo
{
    private int x;
    public Foo()
    {
        x = 0;
    }
}
```